# $T_2$-spaces where all non-empty open sets are homeomorphic

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

We say that a $T_2$-space $(X,\tau)$ has *homeomorphic open sets* if every non-empty open set $U\subseteq X$ endowed with the subspace topology is homeomorphic to $(X,\tau)$.

The rationals with the Euclidean topology are an example of a space with homemorphic open sets, as well as $\{0,1\}^\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal and $\{0,1\}$ carries the discrete topology.

Is there for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$ a space of cardinality $\kappa$ with homeomorphic open sets?

---

**Edit.** Apologies for falsely claiming that $\{0,1\}^\lambda$ is a space with homeomorphic open sets - Joel David Hamkins' comment below gives an argument refuting my claim.

Comment: If you remove a point from $2^\omega$, it is no longer compact, and so not homeomorphic to the whole space $2^\omega$. Doesn't this refute your claim about $\{0,1\}^\lambda$?

Comment: You are right - thanks Joel! I'll add this as a note in the question

Comment: Do you have any uncountable examples of this phenomenon?

Comment: I thought I had :-) but now it looks like $\mathbb{Q}$ is the only example I have. It would also be interesting to see another countable example, not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I wonder whether $2^{<\kappa}$ for uncountable ordinals $\kappa$ would be an uncountable example analogous to $\mathbb{Q}$, but I worry that cofinality differences in the order could show up in the homeomorphism types of different open sets.

Comment: You might be interested in the classic [Toronto space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_space) problem: is there an uncountable Hausdorff space $X$ such that any $Y \subseteq X$ with $|Y| = |X|$ is homeomorphic to $X$? It's still open, even for size $\aleph_1$, AFAIK. Note that your problem is different as it asks for open sets etc.

Comment: There are related notions of $B$-homogenous: a space is called that if there is a base $\mathcal{B}$ for the open sets such for every $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ there is a homeomorphism $h$ of $X$ such that $h[B_1] = B_2$. Open problem: is every topological vector space $B$-homogenous (yes for locally convex).

Comment: And a zero-dimensional space $X$ is called *strongly homogeneous* when every non-empty clopen subset of $X$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Baire space $\omega^\omega$ has homeomorphic open sets: it is an immediate consequence of  the fact that it is the unique nonempty zero-dimensional Polish space, up to homeomorphism, every compact subset of whose has empty interior (theorem 7.7 in Kechris). In fact we actually have better:

> **Proposition.** For every infinite set $X$ with the discrete topology, $X^\omega$ has homeomorphic open sets.

*Proof.* Let $U \subseteq X$ be nonempty open. I claim that $U$ is a union of exactly $\kappa$ disjoint cones, where $\kappa = |X|$. To see this, it is enough to show that $U$ is a union of $\leqslant \kappa$ disjoint cones, as a cone is itself a union of $\kappa$ disjoint cones. But if $T \subseteq X^{< \omega}$ is a nonempty tree such that $[T] = U^c$, then $U$ is the disjoint union of all cones $N_s$ where $s \notin T$ but $s_{\restriction |s| - 1} \in T$.

Now, writing $U$ as a union of $\kappa$ disjoint cones, we can get a homeomorphism between $U$ and $X$ by gluing together homeomorphism between these cones and cones of the form $N_{(x)}$, $x \in X$.

So the answer to Dominic's question is positive at least for cardinals of the form $\kappa^\omega$.

**Edit:** Will Brian remarked, in the comments, that the same argument actually enables to show that the subspace of $X^\omega$ whose elements are eventually constant also had homeomorphic open sets. So for every infinite cardinal, there exists a space with homeomorphic open sets.

Comment: Every nonempty compact subset of $\omega^\omega$ has nonempty interior? What about singletons?

Comment: @NikWeaver: I think it should say *empty* interior.

Comment: Yes @NikWeaver, Will Brian was right: it was "empty interior". I edit to correct the mistake.

Comment: However @DominicvanderZypen, maybe you should not accept the answer yet, the question is still interesting as we have no example for a lot of cardinals. It would be nice if other people could look at this question.

Comment: Doesn't your argument apply equally well to the subspace of $X^\omega$ consisting of eventually constant sequences? It's still true that the closed sets can be expressed as trees, and it's still true that every open set is a union of disjoint cones. But this subspace has cardinality $|X|$, so this version of the argument would work for any infinite cardinal.

Comment: @N.deRancourt I like your answer so much that I have accepted it! Answers from other people are of course much welcome, too.

Comment: Of course @WillBrian you are right! That's nice, maybe you should post it as an answer? Or if you prefer, I can add it on my answer.

Comment: @N.deRancourt: Go ahead and add it to your answer -- it's just a minor variation on your idea.